# How can I obtain a computer readable model of Dr. Gerhard Michal's biological pathways map?

Tags: bioinformatics, metabolism, theoretical-biology

I want to run simulations of various metabolic pathways – the project could end up becoming quite large, and having a machine readable chart would make thing a lot easier. Does anyone know if there is a machine readable file of Dr. Gerhard Michal's famous metabolic pathways chart?

Comment: Can you think of any format you would like this map to be in?

Comment: If yes, you could maybe email ROCHE directly to ask. I am not so familiar with the standard methods used in numerical simulation of metabolic pathway to know whether there is such thing as a standard format for this kind of data.

Comment: Can you give more details about the sort of simulations you want to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roche's [Biochemical Pathways](http://biochemical-pathways.com/) works as a big png image and just put labels on the map. But you could try to extract data using queries like http://biochemical-pathways.com/pol/fts/query?query=Glutarate
It seems to be legal as it's [not prohibited](http://www.roche.com/legal_statement.htm).

[Escher](http://escher.github.io/) is a good pathway visualization tool where you can save map in JSON or SVG.

Another choice is [VMH](http://vmh.uni.lu/) (Virtual Metabolic Human) - the virtual metabolic human database provides literature-derived information on human metabolism, gut microbial metabolism, nutrition, and diseases.

[Reactome](https://reactome.org/) has two layer map - first layer is biological interactions, second layer is pathways.